# Only testing for the first item in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a piecewise function, and testing it on single items works perfect. However, when a list is inputted it only runs for the first item in the list. This is my code:

```
def pwfun(x):
    myList = []
    
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for i in x:
            if i < -1:
                if isinstance(i, float):
                    myList.append(round(-2 * (i + 1), 2))
                else:
                    myList.append(int(-2 * (i + 1)))
            elif i <= 1 and i >= -1:
                myList.append(0)
            else:
                if isinstance(i, float):
                    myList.append(round(i**2 - 1, 2))
                else: 
                    mylist.append(int(i**2 - 1))
            return myList
    else:
        if x < -1:
            if isinstance(x, float):
                return(round(-2 * (x + 1), 2))
            else: 
                return(int(-2 * (x + 1)))
        elif x <= 1 and x >= -1:
            return(0)
        else:
            if isinstance(x, float):
                return(round(x**2 - 1, 2))
            else:
                return(int(x**2 -1))
   
x = [-6.2, 0]
pwfun(x)
```

I don't know what to try, I'm new to Python and I don't know what to do at this point. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are returning the function in the `for loop` at every iteration. So, after the first iteration it returns.

To fix it, you should put the `return` outside the `for loop`.

```
def pwfun(x):
    myList = []

    if isinstance(x, list):
        for i in x:
            if i < -1:
                if isinstance(i, float):
                    myList.append(round(-2 * (i + 1), 2))
                else:
                    myList.append(int(-2 * (i + 1)))
            elif i <= 1 and i >= -1:
                myList.append(0)
            else:
                if isinstance(i, float):
                    myList.append(round(i ** 2 - 1, 2))
                else:
                    myList.append(int(i ** 2 - 1))
        return myList
    else:
        if x < -1:
            if isinstance(x, float):
                return (round(-2 * (x + 1), 2))
            else:
                return (int(-2 * (x + 1)))
        elif x <= 1 and x >= -1:
            return (0)
        else:
            if isinstance(x, float):
                return (round(x ** 2 - 1, 2))
            else:
                return (int(x ** 2 - 1))


x = [-6.2, 0]
print(pwfun(x))
```

output:

```
[10.4, 0]
```